# Python - ImportError: No module named 'pymongo' despite pip says "requirement already satisfied" [Windows]

Tags: python, pip, pymongo, monkeyrunner, pymongo-3.x

As the title clearly describes, despite I have successfully installed PyMongo thru [the suggested way](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/installation.html) (executing the command `python -m pip install pymongo`), getting an error like `ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'` when I try to execute a Python script that imports `PyMongo`.

`Python` version: `3.7.0`

`PyMongo` version: `3.7.1` (which says the best match)

p.s. (1) The OS is Windows 10.

(2) The answers to the similar questions did not work.

Edit: Here is the output of the command `python -m easy_install pymongo`:

```
Searching for pymongo
Best match: pymongo 3.7.1
Processing pymongo-3.7.1-py3.7-win-amd64.egg
pymongo 3.7.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\users\talha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.7.1-py3.7-win-amd64.egg
Processing dependencies for pymongo
Finished processing dependencies for pymongo
```

The output of the command `python -m pip install pymongo`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in c:\users\talha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.7.1-py3.7-win-amd64.egg (3.7.1)
```

**The command I execute to simulate Android device through my Python script which uses both `MonkeyRunner` and `PyMongo` modules**:

`monkeyrunner.bat C:\Users\talha\Documents\PyCharmProjects\MonkeyRunner\test.py`

And, here is the full error stacktrace:

```
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script terminated due to an exception
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\talha\Documents\PyCharmProjects\MonkeyRunner\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pymongo import MongoClient
ImportError: No module named pymongo

180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Py.java:304)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:755)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:837)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:917)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1220)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:357)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1173)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1011)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:987)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(C:\Users\talha\Documents\PyCharmProjects\MonkeyRunner\test.py:39)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(C:\Users\talha\Documents\PyCharmProjects\MonkeyRunner\test.py)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1275)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:522)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:225)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:77)
180904 04:34:13.771:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]     at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:189)
```

Comment: Do you have multiple Python's installed?

Comment: No, I don't, the only version is `3.7.0`. @Keith

Comment: Please add the code snippet that shows the error, and the traceback.

Comment: Added to the original post. @Keith

Comment: Do you have the mongod process running ?

Comment: Does it work from a cmd prompt?

Comment: Connecting to a remote MongoDB server. @JoeA

Comment: No, it does not. @Keith

Comment: It looks like it's being run by jpython. But it's hard to tell from here what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Things installed with `pip` and `easy_install` can end up in different places, depending on a few things.

Here are some troubleshooting thoughts...

Adding

```
import sys ; print(sys.path)
```

Somewhere in your script will print a (long) list of paths that python searches. Is pymongo in one of those directories?

If you know where it's installed, you can apply the following *hack* to make it work:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/parent/dir python myscript.py
```

(Setting environment variables in windows is different. Adjustments probably required.)

Using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) is a one-time step that you can take that will at least put all your problems in the same place. Once you have it installed and set up, everything you install will go in your virtualenv. It's also nice to be able to switch environments easily.

Comment: Yeah, the path contains the PyMongo folder `C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\pymongo-3.7.1-py3.7-win-amd64.egg` since I have already added the folder that shows the PyMongo installation folder to the PATH manually.

Comment: When I use the Python shell, I am able to import PyMongo. But when I try to execute my Python script thru `MonkeyRunner` (an Android test tool), it does not work, and throws the error I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: PyCharm might be using a completely different python/environment. I'm not familiar. If you run a script using pycharm and do `import os; print(os.__file__)`, that will tell you what python environment pycharm is using.

Comment: No, I do not run the script through PyCharm since the script is triggered by `MonkeyRunner` which is a tool available under the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an important point: `monkeyrunner` is another python interpreter based on jython, so it doesn't matter how many other python interpreters you have installed and what packages installed with them using `easy_install` or `pip`.

If you want a python based solution similar to `monkeyrunner` check [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient).

Comment: Just installed `AndroidViewClient`, unfortunately it does not support `Python 3`.

Comment: True, but there is `pymongo` for 2.7.x, so using `virtualenv` or `pyenv` you can create a separate environment to run your scripts.